# After windows update, screen goes dark

Tags: windows, display

I updated my windows and after update, screen goes not totally dark but almost dark.

Where could by the problem? Some driver missing?

[image]

I have an HP Pavilion G6 notebook.

Comment: Please provide us with exact laptop model.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.